# How to 'serve' sub folders?

Tags: vue.js, serve

I have different directories in my dist folder. How can I serve them with [vercel/serve](https://github.com/vercel/serve)?

`localhost/foo` should serve the build of `foo` folder

`localhost/bar` should serve the build of `bar` folder

these sub folders are vue(2) builds

[image]

I can serve `foo` by `serve -s dist/foo`

But is it possible to `serve -s dist` all subfolders?

It shows file system by this way,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
Just run `serve dist` or `serve -s dist`
OR
open terminal in **dist** directory and run `serve`

It always serve all subfolders as well.

And go to http://localhost:3000/foo/, with trailing slash /
Otherwise it will not serve index.html and just list directory.

Comment: I've added another screenshot to my question related to that

Comment: Go to [localhost:8080/foo/](http://localhost:8080/foo/), with trailing slash /, OR you can use [http-server package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

Comment: adding `/` didn't help. I checked the package you shared. still chasing for valid configs to serve sub folders as routes.

Comment: Can you try clicking index.html button in the list?

Comment: I use http-server and it works fine, install by using ```npm install -g http-server``` and just go to dist directory and run ```http-server```